# pandas resample dropna does not apply for all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resampling

When resampling `DataFrame`, `dropna()` seems to work column-wise, which would make measurement inaccurate.

For below data:

```
In [1]: np.random.seed(117)

In [2]: data = pd.DataFrame(
   ...:     np.concatenate((np.random.rand(17), np.full(3, np.nan))).reshape(2, 10).transpose(),
   ...:     index=pd.bdate_range(start='2019-02-04', end='2019-02-15'),
   ...:     columns=['t1', 't2'],
   ...: ).mul(.01).add(1).cumprod().mul(100)

In [3]: data
Out[3]:
               t1     t2
2019-02-04 100.45 100.68
2019-02-05 100.75 101.65
2019-02-06 100.98 102.48
2019-02-07 101.88 103.40
2019-02-08 102.07 104.17
2019-02-11 103.02 104.93
2019-02-12 103.07 105.09
2019-02-13 103.85    NaN
2019-02-14 103.94    NaN
2019-02-15 104.09    NaN
```

If we resample the data for weekly accumulative returns, we want to drop dates after `2019-02-13` in the 2nd period - because column `t2` has no data after that date. But accumulative returns for `t1` is based on the whole period `1.03`:

```
In [4]: data.resample('7D').apply(lambda vv: vv.dropna().pct_change().sum()).mul(100)
Out[4]:
             t1   t2
2019-02-04 1.60 3.43
2019-02-11 1.03 0.15
```

The reason of the problem is - `dropna()` applies to each column separately. This introduces an invalid data point in the resampling result. Is there a pythonic way to only use data during `2019-02-11` and `2019-02-12`, i.e., the desired output should be:

```
In [5]: ???
Out[5]:
             t1   t2
2019-02-04 1.60 3.43
2019-02-11 0.05 0.15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `nan` before you resample your data:

```
data.loc[data.isna().sum(axis=1) == 0, :].resample('7D').apply(lambda vv: vv.pct_change().sum()).mul(100)
```

The result looks like this:

```
                  t1        t2
date                          
2019-02-04  1.604703  3.422393
2019-02-11  0.048534  0.152483
```